# WebRTC support in Headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, p2p, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I have a camera connected to my raspberry pi. I want to stream the live feed from this camera to clients(browsers). Can a headless chrome be used on raspberry pi? I want to use the browser WebRTC api's in raspberry pi application.

Comment: did you even figured this out?

Comment: i guess headless chrome does not support webrtc